# Set values greater than 1 or less than 0 for UIViewPropertyAnimator's fractionComplete

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewpropertyanimator

I'm setting `propertyAnimator?.fractionComplete` to change the position of a view, based on my pan gesture's translation. Later, I'm planning to animate it back to `CGPoint.zero` once the finger lifts. Here's my code:

<kbd>[image: Dragging the square with the cursor]</kbd>

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let squareContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 70, width: 230, height: 30))
    let squareView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    let targetSquareViewOrigin = CGFloat(200)
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 25, y: 140, width: 350, height: 30))
    
    var propertyAnimator: UIViewPropertyAnimator?
    
    var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    var totalTranslation = CGFloat(0) {
        didSet {
            label.text = "Translation: \(totalTranslation.rounded()), percentage: \(totalTranslation / squareContainerView.frame.width)"
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(squareContainerView)
        squareContainerView.addSubview(squareView)
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        squareContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        squareView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        label.text = "Translation: \(totalTranslation.rounded()), percentage: \(totalTranslation / squareContainerView.frame.width)"
        
        panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:(#selector(self.handleGesture(_:))))
        squareContainerView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        
        propertyAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 1, curve: .linear)
        propertyAnimator?.addAnimations {
            self.squareView.frame.origin.x = self.targetSquareViewOrigin
        }
    }
    
    @objc func handleGesture(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        totalTranslation += sender.translation(in: squareContainerView).x
        let fractionComplete = totalTranslation / squareContainerView.frame.width
        propertyAnimator?.fractionComplete = fractionComplete
        
        sender.setTranslation(.zero, in: squareContainerView) /// reset to zero
    }
}
```

The square view is moving, but when the percentage goes above `1` or below `0`, it stops. This makes sense, as its original origin was `CGPoint.zero` and I set a 200 end value with `addAnimations()`.

But, I want it to continue moving, even when the fraction complete goes over. In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewanimating/1649787-fractioncomplete) it says:

> When defining a custom animator, you may allow values greater than 1.0 or less than 0.0 if you support animations running past their beginning or end points.

How can I enable this? Should I create a subclass, and if so, what methods should I override?

Comment: Maybe you can replace `translationInView` with `locationInView`

Comment: While it *sounds* like `.fractionComplete` would allow you to *"continue the path past the endpoint"* it doesn't really work that way. If you look at the definition, you'll see the comment: *Some adopters may choose to give meaning to values less than zero and greater than 1 to facilitate over and undershooting.* What is your ultimate goal? Are you trying to allow the user to drag the blue view? Or change its position based on dragging in the red view? `UIViewPropertyAnimator` may not be the best approach.

Comment: @DonMag I'm actually adding and removing child view controllers by swiping left and right, and I want it to overshoot / rubber band if the user swipes too much. I originally only used an `UIViewPropertyAnimator` for the `.ended` state of the pan (to animate it back to the start), and just set the `origin.x` during the `.changed` state, but I also wanted to animate the alpha of a `UIVisualEffectView`. Based on previous answers it seems that is only possible with `UIViewPropertyAnimator`'s `fractionComplete`.

Comment: On second thought, I could probably make a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` for the `UIVisualEffectView`, and just change the `origin.x` of the view controller during `.changed`. I'll try it out.